# reading hex from text file and split it in c program

Tags: c

I am reading from text file hex, but I want to split it to  two digits?

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char hexa[100];
    FILE *fp = fopen ("data2.txt", "r+");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", hexa);
    printf("\n first data = %s \n", hexa);
    printf("\n first digit= %s \n", hexa[1]);
    printf("\n second digit= %s \n", hexa[2]);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I read from the file successfully, but the result is:

```
first data = 16

segmentation fault
```

Comment: the statement: `#include <studio.h>`   should be: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: the returned type from the `main()` function is always `int`, but can be `void` if running with no OS.   Yes, I know that 'visual studio' allows `void` but that is not standard

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen for data2.txt failed" );  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  When using the '%s' input format specifier, always use a 'max length' modifier, that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid any buffer overflow events, which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Exactly how is the input file: `data2.txt` contents formatted?  are there spaces between pairs of hex digits? are there newline characters? etc.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hexa[1]` and `hexa[2]` are characters, but you're printing them as though they were strings, that is, character arrays.  Since they're in the range 0-255, and this range of memory is inaccessible, you get a crash.

Do this:

```
printf("\n first digit= %c \n", hexa[1]);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you may want to use:

```
printf("\n first data = %s \n", hexa);
printf("\n first digit= %c \n", hexa[1]);
printf("\n second digit= %c \n", hexa[2]);
```

`hexa` decays to a pointer to char, and `hexa[1]` is a char. The arguments corresponding to `"%s"` expected by `printf()` are `char *`s, so passing `hexa[1]` causes segmentation fault. To print a single character, you should use `"%c"` specifier.